# Laravel, common page for guest and user, session table user_id null

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8, laravel-authentication, laravel-session

In session table, user id is null when user visit guest page.

```
Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index',])->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:user']], function () {

    Route::get('/dashboard', [HomeController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');

});
```

When user visit dashboard, session table has user id and same user goes to home page user id is now set as null in session table.

Comment: Do you manually save session data to table? If yes, why don't you use Laravel's built in session helper function to achieve what you want to do?

Comment: I am using default session helper of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', [HomeController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
});
```

Comment: Problem is home page not dashboard, home page is for both user and guest.

Comment: Seen from your code, saying that the home page doesn't require authentication. so home page can be accessed for both user and guest. maybe you need `@auth user activity @endauth` or `@guest guest activity @endguest` ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#authentication-directives

Comment: This is not about the blade, its about session table.